# menus and per page sub menus

Tags: theming, routes, navigation

I have my primary navigation (which is hard-coded into the theme). What I want is for a sub-menu (depending on the page) to appear in the left sidebar.

For example, if they click on the primary link for "bears" then the left sidebar menu might have "black bears" and "brown bears". How can these sub menus be accomplished? I don't want sub-menus these hard coded (i.e. easily configured by the client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)